# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 58

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-tomee, unsupported-class-version

I have included TomEE with Eclipse in order to start developing dynamic web projects (I am still new to it).

Before adding the project to the TomEE server, I am able to start it without any problem.

But when I add the project to the server and try to run it I get the error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 58`

#### What I tried to do in order to solve it:

- Changing the server port number
- Deleting and recreating the server
- Checking the `web.xml` file to make sure the servlet mapping is fine
- Reconfiguring the project's target runtime
- Reconfiguring the runtime environments of eclipse

#### Versions:

- TomEE: v8.0.3 plume
- JDK: 15.0.1
- Eclipse: 4.17.0

### Code of the test project

#### TestServlet.java

```
package my.test.project;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Hello this is a test");
        out.close();
    }
}
```

#### Web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>my.test.project.TestServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

#### Error in console log after executing

```
Nov 06, 2020 1:06:18 PM jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/TestProject]]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/TestProject]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEERuntimeException: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to create annotation scanner for web module TestProject: Unable to read class definition for my.test.project.TestServlet
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.loadApplication(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:2363)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1198)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1131)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5052)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to create annotation scanner for web module TestProject: Unable to read class definition for my.test.project.TestServlet
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.addWebModule(DeploymentLoader.java:886)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.load(DeploymentLoader.java:233)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.loadApplication(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:2361)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to read class definition for my.test.project.TestServlet
    at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.readClassDef(AnnotationFinder.java:1180)
    at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.<init>(AnnotationFinder.java:153)
    at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.<init>(AnnotationFinder.java:166)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory$OpenEJBAnnotationFinder.<init>(FinderFactory.java:546)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.newFinder(FinderFactory.java:267)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.create(FinderFactory.java:80)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.createFinder(FinderFactory.java:69)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.addWebModule(DeploymentLoader.java:878)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 58
    at org.apache.xbean.asm7.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:195)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm7.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:176)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm7.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:162)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm7.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:283)
    at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.readClassDef(AnnotationFinder.java:1176)
    ... 42 more

Nov 06, 2020 1:06:18 PM jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/TestProject]]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/TestProject]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEERuntimeException: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to create annotation scanner for web module TestProject: Unable to read class definition for my.test.project.TestServlet
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.loadApplication(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:2363)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1198)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1131)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5052)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to create annotation scanner for web module TestProject: Unable to read class definition for my.test.project.TestServlet
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.addWebModule(DeploymentLoader.java:886)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.load(DeploymentLoader.java:233)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.loadApplication(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:2361)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to read class definition for my.test.project.TestServlet
    at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.readClassDef(AnnotationFinder.java:1180)
    at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.<init>(AnnotationFinder.java:153)
    at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.<init>(AnnotationFinder.java:166)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory$OpenEJBAnnotationFinder.<init>(FinderFactory.java:546)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.newFinder(FinderFactory.java:267)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.create(FinderFactory.java:80)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.createFinder(FinderFactory.java:69)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.addWebModule(DeploymentLoader.java:878)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 58
    at org.apache.xbean.asm7.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:195)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm7.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:176)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm7.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:162)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm7.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:283)
    at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.readClassDef(AnnotationFinder.java:1176)
    ... 42 more

Nov 06, 2020 1:06:18 PM jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/TestProject]]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/TestProject]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEERuntimeException: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to create annotation scanner for web module TestProject: Unable to read class definition for my.test.project.TestServlet
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.loadApplication(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:2363)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1198)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1131)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5052)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to create annotation scanner for web module TestProject: Unable to read class definition for my.test.project.TestServlet
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.addWebModule(DeploymentLoader.java:886)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.load(DeploymentLoader.java:233)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.loadApplication(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:2361)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to read class definition for my.test.project.TestServlet
    at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.readClassDef(AnnotationFinder.java:1180)
    at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.<init>(AnnotationFinder.java:153)
    at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.<init>(AnnotationFinder.java:166)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory$OpenEJBAnnotationFinder.<init>(FinderFactory.java:546)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.newFinder(FinderFactory.java:267)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.create(FinderFactory.java:80)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.createFinder(FinderFactory.java:69)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.addWebModule(DeploymentLoader.java:878)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 58
    at org.apache.xbean.asm7.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:195)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm7.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:176)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm7.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:162)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm7.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:283)
    at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.readClassDef(AnnotationFinder.java:1176)
    ... 42 more

Nov 06, 2020 1:06:18 PM jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Nov 06, 2020 1:06:18 PM jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFO: Stopping service [Catalina]
Nov 06, 2020 1:06:18 PM org.apache.openejb.server.SimpleServiceManager stop
INFO: Stopping server services
Nov 06, 2020 1:06:18 PM jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl invoke
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
```

#### Project Facets

[image: Project Facets]

The help would be very much appreciated as I've been at it for quite some time but can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

Thank you.

Comment: The error indicates the different Java versions used (probably by your build tool / Eclipse / TomEE).

Comment: You are trying to run code compiled for Java 14 (class file version 58) on an older version of Java

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have mentioned your version is JDK: 15.0.1
and the project's Java Facet is 14.

FYI:

- Java 13 uses major version 57
- Java 14 uses major version 58
- Java 15 uses major version 59
- Java 16 uses major version 60

The version can be checked with:

```
javap -verbose MyClass | grep "major"
```